# ValueError: could not convert string '' to int32 at row 0, column 115

Tags: python-3.x

> ```
> def read_pict_data(path_2_data):
>     path_2_data=r"C:\Users\ichat\Desktop\dataa.txt"
>     patterns_all = read_pict_data(path_2_data)
>
> """ Read dataa.text. 4 binary images of shape (32, 32).
>     
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     path_2_data : str
>         Path to data.
>     
>     Returns
>     ----------
>     numpy.ndarray
>         Data as array of shape (4, 1024)
>     """
>     ndim = 1024
>     return np.loadtxt(path_2_data, delimiter=" ", dtype=int).reshape(-1, ndim)
>     
> # Get first 3 images.
> patterns = patterns_all[:3,:]
> print(patterns.shape)
> ```

hello, im trying to read 4 binary images from this txt file [dataa.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG5OW.png),

+1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1
+1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1
-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
-1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1
-1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1
-1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1
-1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1
-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1
+1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1

but it returns this error : "ValueError: could not convert string '' to int32 at row 0, column 115"

i cant find what its wrong with that, if i change the numbers of elements/line it still appears the same error in other positions. Anyone experiencing the same?

Comment: It failed to convert an empty string to a number, which seems reasonable. What is the data causing this? Make sure you provide a [mcve]!

Comment: need to see the contents of example of the `dataa.txt` file.